# Make all changes by a user reversible on linux

Tags: linux, version-control

Is it possible to safe all changes a user does in his home directory?

The idea is to be able to recover a home directory if a file is deleted or overwritten. My problem is having an old family member (80+ years) who wants to learn how to use a computer. For me it would be easier to recover the home directory from any abuse or mistakes that the user might do.

Is there an easy solution, which is quite failsafe?

Comment: Yes, if you don't mind getting your hands [dirty](http://www.nilfs.org/en/).

Comment: A comment on a comment: the original site Ignacio pointed to has since been abandoned by the original developers, and re-opened by a bunch of thugs, who use it to lure customers to porn websites. The **true** NILFS Website is http://nilfs.sourceforge.net/en/

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, Dropbox allows you to roll back files to previous versions (https://www.dropbox.com/help/11/en), and to recover deleted files (https://www.dropbox.com/help/296/en). I'm guessing a person who is really new to computers may initially get by with the free 2GB, so you could store the entire homedir on Dropbox.

There <del>is also</del> used to be Ubuntu One (https://one.ubuntu.com/) (which I have never used, though), but which seems to provide a similar service to Dropbox, and which seems to come with 5GB free.
**Update**: Ubuntu One has ceased its cloud storage and synchronization operations since July 31 of 2014.

Other synchronisations (`rsync`, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync), or `unison`, http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) may also be of help, but will require more work from your side in setting up storage space (possibly on a remote host; I use http://rsync.net/ - do inquire for a discount) and `cron` jobs. Note that a synchronization does not prevent you from losing files.

Answer (score 0):

A [versioning filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versioning_file_system) sounds like an appropriate solution to your problem. That way any and all changes could rolled back when needed.

There are a few versioning filesystem implementations for Linux, but all are experimental as you can read from Wikipedia. Depending on the GNU/Linux distribution you're using, [NILFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NILFS) might be an option available straight out of the box, at least Debian and Ubuntu offer it with `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility are copy-on-write filesystems like btrfs. I was told that someone doing a full backup per minute would still need quite some time (like months or years) to fill up the disk space that way.

Answer (score 0):

I've used git (but cvs, subversion or any other versioning system) to store the essential files in my homedir, so that when I mess up or (re)install a machine I quickly have all my stuff.

Another solution could be to put the homedirectory on ZFS and periodically make snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

There's [ZFS](http://zfsonlinux.org/) which does snapshots.

Yet another answer (for completeness), but needs hardware, so probably less fun:

You could have his home dir come from a local NAS, and run something like [FreeNAS](http://freenas.org) with ZFS, which does snapshots. Good news is that you can do cookl things like backups and other things with it. Bad news, it takes a lot of work to get to just "here's your home dir"